# JApplet menus are not visible

Tags: java

I'm a newbie for java and learning for past two months from a book. I've tried a JApplet Menu program from the book.

**MenuDemo.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class MenuDemo implements ActionListener {
    JLabel jlab;

    MenuDemo() {
        JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("Menu Demo");
        jfrm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jfrm.setSize(220, 200);
        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jlab = new JLabel();
        JMenuBar jmb = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu jmFile = new JMenu("File");
        JMenuItem jmiOpen = new JMenuItem("Open");
        JMenuItem jmiClose = new JMenuItem("Close");
        JMenuItem jmiSave = new JMenuItem("Save");
        JMenuItem jmiExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        jmFile.add(jmiOpen);
        jmFile.add(jmiClose);
        jmFile.add(jmiSave);
        jmFile.addSeparator();
        jmFile.add(jmiExit);
        jmb.add(jmFile);
        JMenu jmOptions = new JMenu("Options");
        JMenu jmColors = new JMenu("Colors");
        JMenuItem jmiRed = new JMenuItem("Red");
        JMenuItem jmiGreen = new JMenuItem("Green");
        JMenuItem jmiBlue = new JMenuItem("Blue");
        jmColors.add(jmiRed);
        jmColors.add(jmiGreen);
        jmColors.add(jmiBlue);
        jmOptions.add(jmColors);
        JMenu jmPriority = new JMenu("Priority");
        JMenuItem jmiHigh = new JMenuItem("High");
        JMenuItem jmiLow = new JMenuItem("Low");
        jmPriority.add(jmiHigh);
        jmPriority.add(jmiLow);
        jmOptions.add(jmPriority);
        JMenuItem jmiReset = new JMenuItem("Reset");
        jmOptions.addSeparator();
        jmOptions.add(jmiReset);
        jmb.add(jmOptions);
        JMenu jmHelp = new JMenu("Help");
        JMenuItem jmiAbout = new JMenuItem("About");
        jmHelp.add(jmiAbout);
        jmb.add(jmHelp);
        jmiOpen.addActionListener(this);
        jmiClose.addActionListener(this);
        jmiSave.addActionListener(this);
        jmiExit.addActionListener(this);
        jmiRed.addActionListener(this);
        jmiGreen.addActionListener(this);
        jmiBlue.addActionListener(this);
        jmiHigh.addActionListener(this);
        jmiLow.addActionListener(this);
        jmiReset.addActionListener(this);
        jmiAbout.addActionListener(this);
        jfrm.add(jlab);
        jfrm.setJMenuBar(jmb);
        jfrm.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        String comStr = ae.getActionCommand();
        if (comStr.equals("Exit"))
            System.exit(0);
        jlab.setText(comStr + " Selected");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MenuDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But it gives the below exception.

```
load: MenuDemo is not public or has no public constructor.
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class sun.applet.AppletPanel can not access a
member of class MenuDemo with modifiers ""
        at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:102)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:436)
        at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(AppletPanel.java:799)
        at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(AppletPanel.java:728)
        at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:378)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So I changed first three lines from class as below:

```
public class MenuDemo extends JApplet implements ActionListener {
JLabel jlab;
public void MenuDemo() {
```

Now the applet window is visible but without menus. As a newbie how can I resolve it.

Thank you.

Comment: Indent your code for better life.

Comment: You need to have at least one `public` class from which `main` will be called by jvm. In your case, add `public` modifier to `class MenuDemo`

Comment: It seems like you resolved your original problem with the missing `public` yourself, so you should probably change the title of your question to why the menus aren't visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>A constructor does not have a return type. Remove `void` from the following line.</strike>

**EDIT**

Class definition:

```
public class MenuDemo extends JApplet implements ActionListener {
```

Change `public MenuDemo()` to `public void init()`

Create two functions in your class as follows.

```
public void start(){}
public void stop(){}
```

change

```
jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

to

```
jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: Your error does not reproduce on my system. It works fine.

Comment: Wah! May I know did you use it by MenuDemo.html? because in the book they mentioned to run it like that with appletviewer or how did you run it?

Comment: You need to atleast extend from a JApplet for that to work

Comment: Yes. I did it in my code. I apologize Abdul for it looks like you are spoon-feeding to me.

Comment: You are right. It should go like this as other Applets have init, start, stop. Probably I should not depend on the book I am reading currently. Thank you Genius.